# Android - Share data between apps over the internet

Tags: android, share

I want to build a app with sharing option. I mean that users can pass simple data between their contacts, that use the app. And I don't want to use servers of mine.

Is it possible to use existing platforms such as Facebook, Google, or even with android APi only?
If it can be done, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [gcm - Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)

Nevertheless, for this you will have to use some kind of server to send push messages.

Comment: But I need to pay for server for it?

Comment: Direct communication would require that one of the devices is server and other would be client, but you can never know the ip for the device because it changes mobile network cells, or changes WiFi routers and so on. You need some kind of server with which you will be able to communicate. Your device app can contact server, and server will be able to send message to other device app using gcm. There are a lot of free hosting sites and you can use simple php script for the server.

Comment: I understood. Is Google also provides an option to create a server?

Comment: I don't know that for sure but it provides helper classes for client and a server http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/client-javadoc/index.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/server-javadoc/index.html

Comment: maybe this will help you http://www.warriorforum.com/programming-talk/313537-free-php-hosting-google.html

Answer (score 0):

I created the free and Open Source web service [cross copy](http://cross-copy.net) to do file and message transfer between devices via simple RESTful commands:

waiting for messages to appear "on the given codeword" (long polling):
**GET   http://cross-copy.net/api/any_codeword_you_like**

sening a message in body to all waiting clients:
**PUT   http://cross-copy.net/api/any_codeword_you_like**

Both devices must use the same codeword and hence it must be agreed upon (displayed on screen, QR-Code, prediefined, computed by geo location or what ever fits for your application. More infos are available in the [readme at GitHub](https://github.com/rodja/cross-copy/blob/master/README.md).